# How do I add first and second name fields on a login page

Tags: php, html, forms, input, authentication

I would like to know the code to add first and second name fields into my `phpDolphin` login page and also make them display on the person's profile. 
I've already tried to add the fields, but my coding is so wrong.

At the moment, the profile displays a username of which the individual entered upon signing up. I want the profile to display the first and second name entered at login page instead of the username.

I have added this code into a file called **classes.php** :

```
public $firstname;                              // The inserted firstname
public $secondname;                             // The inserted secondname
```

and i have entered this code into the file where the login page is coded:

```
   <input type="text" id="short" name="firstname" placeholder="{$lng->firstname" />
                                    <input type="text" id="short" name="secondname" placeholder="{$lng->secondname" />
```

Remember, i didn't code this myself, its a script called phpDolphin, and i'm just trying to add to it!

I would very much appreciate some help. Thanks in advance, Will.

If you would like to see the site which contains the login page, heres the link: http://www.social.flamboyantent.co.uk/ 
**EDIT**

there's over 4 thousand lines of code in classes.php alone. If you would like the full file let me know.

```
  function getProfile($start, $value) {
$profile = $this->profile_data;
$this->profile_id = $profile['idu'];

// If the username exist
if(!empty($profile['idu'])) {
  $relationship = $this->verifyRelationship($this->id, $this->profile_id, 0);

  // Check privacy
  switch($profile['private']) {
    case 0:
      break;
    case 1:
      // Check if the username is not same with the profile
      if($this->profile !== $this->username) {
        return $this->showError('profile_private');
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      // Check relationship
      if(!$relationship) {
        return $this->showError('profile_semi_private');
      }
      break;
  }

  // Allowed types
  $allowedType = $this->listTypes('profile');
  $allowedDates = $this->listDates('profile');

  // If the $start value is 0, empty the query;
  if($start == 0) {
    $start = '';
  } else {
    // Else, build up the query
    $start = 'AND messages.id < \''.$this->db->real_escape_string($start).'\'';
  }

  // Decide if the query will include only public messages or not
  $public = ($this->username == $this->profile) ? '' : 'AND messages.public = 1';
  if(in_array($value, $allowedType)) {
    $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM messages, users WHERE messages.uid = '%s' AND messages.type = '%s' AND messages.uid = users.idu %s %s ORDER BY messages.id DESC LIMIT %s", $this->db->real_escape_string($profile['idu']), $this->db->real_escape_string($value), $public, $start, ($this->per_page + 1));
    $value = '\''.$value.'\'';
  } elseif(in_array($value, $allowedDates)) {
    $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM messages, users WHERE messages.uid = '%s' AND extract(YEAR_MONTH from `time`) = '%s' AND messages.uid = users.idu %s %s ORDER BY messages.id DESC LIMIT %s", $this->db->real_escape_string($profile['idu']), $this->db->real_escape_string($value), $public, $start, ($this->per_page + 1));
    $value = '\''.$value.'\'';
  } else {
    $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM messages, users WHERE messages.uid = '%s' AND messages.uid = users.idu %s %s ORDER BY messages.id DESC LIMIT %s", $this->db->real_escape_string($profile['idu']), $public, $start, ($this->per_page + 1));
    $value = '\'\'';
  }
  return $this->getMessages($query, 'loadProfile', $value);
} else {
  return $this->showError('profile_not_exist');
}


 }

  function getSubscriptionsList() {
    // The query to select the subscribed users
    $query = sprintf("SELECT `leader` FROM `relations` WHERE `subscriber` = '%s'", $this->db->real_escape_string($this->id));

    // Run the query
    $result = $this->db->query($query);

    // The array to store the subscribed users
    $subscriptions = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $subscriptions[] = $row['leader'];
    }

    // Close the query
    $result->close();

    // Return the subscriptions list (e.g: 13,22,19)
    return implode(',', $subscriptions);
  }

  public function profileData($username = null, $id = null) {
    // The query to select the profile
    // If the $id is set (used in Subscribe function for profiels) then search for the ID
    if($id) {
      $query = sprintf("SELECT `idu`, `username`, `email`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `location`, `website`, `bio`, `date`, `facebook`, `twitter`, `gplus`, `image`, `private`, `background`, `privacy`, `born`, `cover`, `verified`, `gender`, `email_new_friend` FROM `users` WHERE `idu` = '%s'", $this->db->real_escape_string($id));
    } else {
      $query = sprintf("SELECT `idu`, `username`, `email`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `location`, `website`, `bio`, `date`, `facebook`, `twitter`, `gplus`, `image`, `private`, `background`, `privacy`, `born`, `cover`, `verified`, `gender`, `email_new_friend` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '%s'", $this->db->real_escape_string($username));
    }

    // Run the query
    $result = $this->db->query($query);

    return $result->fetch_assoc();
  }

  function fetchProfile($profile) {
    global $LNG, $CONF;
    $coverImage = ((!empty($profile['cover'])) ? $profile['cover'] : 'default.png');
    $coverAvatar = ((!empty($profile['image'])) ? $profile['image'] : 'default.png');
    $cover = '<div class="twelve columns">
          <div class="cover-container">
            <div class="cover-content">
              <a onclick="gallery(\''.$coverImage.'\', \''.$profile['idu'].$profile['username'].'\', \'covers\')" id="'.$coverImage.'"><div class="cover-image" style="background-position: center; background-image: url('.$this->url.'/thumb.php?src='.((!empty($profile['cover'])) ? $profile['cover'] : 'default.png').'&w=900&h=300&t=c)">
              </div></a>
              <div class="cover-description">
                <div class="cover-avatar-content">
                  <div class="cover-avatar">
                    <a onclick="gallery(\''.$coverAvatar.'\', \''.$profile['idu'].$profile['username'].'\', \'avatars\')" id="'.$coverAvatar.'"><span id="avatar'.$profile['idu'].$profile['username'].'"><img src="'.$this->url.'/thumb.php?src='.$coverAvatar.'&t=a&w=150&h=150" /></span></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cover-description-content">
                  <span id="author'.$profile['idu'].$profile['username'].'"></span><span id="time'.$profile['idu'].$profile['username'].'"></span><div class="cover-username"><a href="'.$this->url.'/index.php?a=profile&u='.$profile['username'].'">'.realName($profile['username'], $profile['first_name'], $profile['last_name']).'</a>'.((!empty($profile['verified'])) ? '<img src="'.$this->url.'/'.$CONF['theme_url'].'/images/icons/verified.png" title="'.$LNG['verified_user'].'" />' : '').'</div>
                  <div class="cover-description-buttons"><div id="subscribe'.$profile['idu'].'">'.$this->getSubscribe(null, null, null).'</div>'.$this->chatButton($profile['idu'], $profile['username'], 1).'</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>';
    return $cover;
  }

  function getProfileCard($profile) {
    global $LNG, $CONF;
    $coverImage = ((!empty($profile['cover'])) ? $profile['cover'] : 'default.png');
    $coverAvatar = ((!empty($profile['image'])) ? $profile['image'] : 'default.png');
    $subscribe = $this->getSubscribe(null, null, null);
    $card = '
      <div class="profile-card-cover"><img src="'.$this->url.'/thumb.php?src='.((!empty($profile['cover'])) ? $profile['cover'] : 'default.png').'&w=900&h=300&t=c"></div>
      <div class="profile-card-avatar">
        <a href="'.$this->url.'/index.php?a=profile&u='.$profile['username'].'"><img src="'.$this->url.'/thumb.php?src='.$coverAvatar.'&t=a&w=112&h=112" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="profile-card-info">
        <a href="'.$this->url.'/index.php?a=profile&u='.$profile['username'].'"><span id="author'.$profile['idu'].$profile['username'].'"></span><span id="time'.$profile['idu'].$profile['username'].'"></span><div class="cover-username">'.realName($profile['username'], $profile['first_name'], $profile['last_name']).''.((!empty($profile['verified'])) ? '<img src="'.$this->url.'/'.$CONF['theme_url'].'/images/icons/verified.png" title="'.$LNG['verified_user'].'" />' : '').'</div></a>
      </div>
      '.((!empty($profile['bio'])) ? '<div class="profile-card-divider"></div><div class="profile-card-bio">'.$profile['bio'].'</div>' : '').'
      '.((!empty($subscribe)) ? '
      <div class="profile-card-divider"></div>
      <div class="profile-card-buttons"><div class="profile-card-buttons-container"><div id="subscribe'.$profile['idu'].'">'.$subscribe.'</div>'.$this->chatButton($profile['idu'], $profile['username'], 1).'</div></div>' : '').'
    ';
    return $card;
  }

  function fetchProfileWidget($username, $name, $image) {
    global $LNG;
    $widget =  '<div class="sidebar-container widget-welcome">
            <div class="sidebar-content">
              <div class="sidebar-header">'.$LNG['welcome'].'</div>
              <div class="sidebar-inner">
                <div class="sidebar-avatar"><a href="'.$this->url.'/index.php?a=profile&u='.$username.'"><img src="'.$this->url.'/thumb.php?src='.$image.'&t=a&w=50&h=50" /></a></div>
                <div class="sidebar-avatar-desc">
                  <a href="'.$this->url.'/index.php?a=profile&u='.$username.'">'.((!empty($name) ? $name : $username)).'</a>
                  <div class="sidebar-avatar-edit"><a href="'.$this->url.'/index.php?a=settings">'.$LNG['admin_ttl_edit_profile'].'</a></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>';
    return $widget;
  }
```

**Code for profile from profile.php**

```
    <?php
function PageMain() {
    global $TMPL, $LNG, $CONF, $db, $loggedIn, $settings;

if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password']) || isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])) {    
    $verify = $loggedIn->verify();

    if(empty($verify['username'])) {
        // If fake cookies are set, or they are set wrong, delete everything and redirect to home-page
        $loggedIn->logOut();
        header("Location: ".$CONF['url']."/index.php?a=welcome");
    }

    // If the $_GET user is empty, define default user as current logged in user, else redirect to home-pag
    if($_GET['u'] == '') {
        $_GET['u'] = (!empty($verify['username']) ? $verify['username'] : header("Location: ".$CONF['url']."/index.php?a=welcome"));
    }

    // If the current user is the same with the viewed profile, display the Message Form
    if($verify['username'] == $_GET['u']) {
        $skin = new skin('shared/top'); $top = '';

        $TMPL['theme_url'] = $CONF['theme_url'];
        $TMPL['private_message'] = $verify['privacy'];
        $TMPL['avatar'] = $verify['image'];
        $TMPL['url'] = $CONF['url'];

        $top = $skin->make();
    }
}

// Start displaying the Feed
$feed = new feed();
$feed->db = $db;
$feed->url = $CONF['url'];
$feed->user = $verify;
$feed->id = $verify['idu'];
$feed->username = $verify['username'];
$feed->per_page = $settings['perpage'];
$feed->time = $settings['time'];
$feed->censor = $settings['censor'];
$feed->smiles = $settings['smiles'];
$feed->c_per_page = $settings['cperpage'];
$feed->c_start = 0;
$feed->l_per_post = $settings['lperpost'];

if($verify['username']) {
    $feed->updateStatus($verify['offline']);
}

// If the $_GET user is empty, define default user as current logged in user, else redirect to home-pag
if($_GET['u'] == '') {
    $_GET['u'] = (!empty($feed->username) ? $feed->username : header("Location: ".$CONF['url']."/index.php?a=welcome"));
}

$feed->profile = $_GET['u'];
$feed->profile_data = $feed->profileData($_GET['u']);
$feed->subscriptionsList = $feed->getSubs($feed->profile_data['idu'], 0, null);
$feed->subscribersList = $feed->getSubs($feed->profile_data['idu'], 1, null);
// $feed->image = $verify['image'];

$TMPL_old = $TMPL; $TMPL = array();
$skin = new skin('shared/rows'); $rows = '';

if(empty($_GET['filter'])) {
    $_GET['filter'] = '';
}
// Allowed types
list($timeline, $message) = $feed->getProfile(0, $_GET['filter']);

if($_GET['r'] == 'subscriptions') {
    if($message !== 1) {
        $top = ''; // Hide the message form
        $feed->s_per_page = $settings['sperpage'];
        $feed->subsList = $feed->getSubs($feed->profile_data['idu'], 0, 0);
        $TMPL['messages'] = $feed->listSubs(0);
        $x = 1;
    } else {
        $TMPL['messages'] = $timeline;
    }
    $title = $LNG['subscriptions'];
} elseif($_GET['r'] == 'subscribers') {
    if($message !== 1) {
        $top = ''; // Hide the message form
        $feed->s_per_page = $settings['sperpage'];
        $feed->subsList = $feed->getSubs($feed->profile_data['idu'], 1, 0);
        $TMPL['messages'] = $feed->listSubs(1);
        $x = 1;
    } else {
        $TMPL['messages'] = $timeline;
    }
    $title = $LNG['subscribers'];
} elseif($_GET['r'] == 'likes') {
    if($message !== 1) {
        $top = ''; // Hide the message form
        $TMPL['messages'] = $feed->getLikes(0, 1);
        $x = 1;
    } else {
        $TMPL['messages'] = $timeline;
    }
    $title = $LNG['likes'];
} else {
    $TMPL['messages'] = $timeline;
}

$rows = $skin->make();

$skin = new skin('profile/sidebar'); $sidebar = '';
// If the username doesn't exist
if($message !== 1) {
    $TMPL['about'] = $feed->fetchProfileInfo($feed->profileData($_GET['u']));
    $TMPL['sidebar'] = $feed->sidebarTypes($_GET['filter'], 'profile');
    $TMPL['dates'] = $feed->sidebarDates($_GET['filter'], 'profile');

    $TMPL['places'] = $feed->sidebarPlaces($feed->profile_data['idu']);

    $TMPL['subscriptions'] = $feed->sidebarSubs(0, $subscriptions, 0);
    $TMPL['subscribers'] = $feed->sidebarSubs(1, $subscribers, 0);
    $TMPL['ad'] = generateAd($settings['ad4']);
} else {
    $skin = new skin('profile/sidebar'); $sidebar = '';
    $TMPL['ad'] = generateAd($settings['ad4']);
}
$sidebar = $skin->make();

$TMPL = $TMPL_old; unset($TMPL_old);
$TMPL['top'] = $top;
$TMPL['rows'] = $rows;
$TMPL['sidebar'] = $sidebar;
$TMPL['cover'] = $feed->fetchProfile($feed->profile_data);

if(isset($_GET['logout']) == 1) {
    $loggedIn->logOut();
    header("Location: ".$CONF['url']."/index.php?a=welcome");
}

$TMPL['url'] = $CONF['url'];
$TMPL['title'] = (!empty($title) ? $title : $LNG['title_profile']).' - '.realName($_GET['u'], $feed->profile_data['first_name'], $feed->profile_data['last_name'], 1).' - '.$settings['title'];

if($x) {
    $skin = new skin('shared/timeline_x');
} else {
    $skin = new skin('shared/timeline');
}


return $skin->make();
}
?>
```

Comment: You said at the moment the profile displays the username and you want it to display the first/ last name instead. Where is the code that displays the username? If you have that working already it should be much easier to work with than this.

Comment: @TimTroiano Hey. I have added the code I think is correct. I included the whole profile.php code too. Let me know if ive given the correct part

Comment: @TimTroiano does that help???